# Saving my game objects in the map with Json in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, save

I have a 3D survival game in Unity with rocks, trees, barrels, etc. I have my saving system in json and I can save almost everything (player status, position, inventory, etc.).
The last things I want to save are my game objects in the map (tree,stone).

So when I destroy for example a tree, it will destroy the object, but of course when I load my saved game it appears again.

I guess I have to save the objects x, y, z coordinates, maybe the rotations, but I dont know how to save if I destroy that object or not (so that the object can be loaded or not if I destroy it).

Can someone please give me an advice or an example how can I do such a thing? (save my objects conditions - destroyed or not, coordinates and rotations - )

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You can create Class , where you can store Name, Position, Rotation, even prefab name,Color everything (you can't serialize gameobjets) and then when scene loaded you can recreate your world based on json. Example having prefab name , you can load it  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html. If some objects destroyed , you can have InMemory representation (List,Dictionary) any collection .When you save a game just serialize your collection again

Answer (score 0):

As @phantasm suggested you need to keep track of prefabs. This suggests that every object in the scene should be a prefab. You may use the following data structure to keep track the scene objects

```
public interface IStorableComponent
{
  string Serialize();
  void Deserialize(string payload);
}

[System.Serializable]
public class StorableObject
{
  public string _name;

  public string prefabPath;

  public Vector3 position;

  public Vector3 rotation;

  public Dictionary<string, string> storedComponents;

  public string Serialize(GameObject gameObject)
  {
    // Populate stored components
    storedComponents = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    IStorableComponent[] components = gameObject.GetComponents<IStorableComponent>();
    foreach (var component in components)
    {
      storedComponents.Add(component.GetType().Name, component.Serialize());
    }

    // Serialize using NewtonSoft
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, when you press save or quit game button, you have to save the prefab name of all objects you want to save and their positions (and other stuff like rotation and scale if you want, but it may slow down the process) and then when you load your game again, you can use the names of your prefabs in order to instantiate them from the resource folder (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PBcvTfbDn0 if you do not know how it works) and then set the position and other saved data to those objects. Loop through the list of all objects you saved and voila:) Hope it makes sense